# Installing multiple modules with minimumversion at once in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure-information-protection

i would like to know if it is possible to install multiple modules in PowerShell (which of course is) but with specifying a minimumversion number.

Let's assume we have two modules to install:

1. AIPService version 1.0.0.5
2. ExchangeOnlineManagement version 2.0.5

Is it possible to do it in one line?

I tried following:

```
Install-Module -Name AIPService, ExchangeOnlineManagement -MinimumVersion 1.0.0.5, 2.0.5
```

Thought that this would work due to the fact, that we are able to list multiple modules.

Comment: Just call `Install-Module` twice. Use `;` to separate the two statements if you want a single-line script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/powershellget/install-module) show, parameter `-MinimumVersion` specifies the minimum version of a **single module** to install.
In your case, you need do add two separate lines for each module to install because you want a different version or use a loop and a Hashtable to install. Something like:

```
$modules = @{
    AIPService               = '1.0.0.5'
    ExchangeOnlineManagement = '2.0.5'
}

$modules.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
    Install-Module -Name $_.Name -MinimumVersion $_.Value
}
```